# Displaying chucks of huge images live

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a sort of setup like... google maps. It has nothing to do with maps but the mechanism seems to be similar.

I have an image ~300MB and the client can drag the picture around having different parts of it in view in the browser. I want to load only the specific parts of the image which the user is looking at, and unload the parts which are out of view (to save RAM).

I thought of breaking the image in 15X15px chunks and load the correct chunks each time but I can't seem to wrap my mind around which technique should I use to actually perform this task.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google maps api: https://developers.google.com/maps/ seems to allow everything I need but it is clumsy and limited for the types of things I want to do. 
It's like solving the problem backwards.. figuring out how to work with the map, and the hiding the map layer... which is... doing a lot of work for nothing.

With that, that seemed to be the best solution out there until I cam acroos this:
Panojs
http://www.dimin.net/software/panojs/
This seems to be super easy to use and quite flexible.

or Zoom.it which is based on SeaDragon which is also super easy to use!
http://www.zoom.it/

Cheers

Comment: ye I agree, learning new stuff is stupid! let's all just stop learning stuff to solve our problems! lol

Comment: It's not about learning new stuff.. it's about learning how to work the Google Maps API, and then not use the maps. Why work so hard if there is something else designed specifically for the purpose I need?

Answer (score 2):

Google Maps breaks up their images (including streetview etc) into smaller chunks. I've seen a lot of people use their own images WITH the Google Maps technology to create their own maps of whatever (one, for example, is a fantasy world/web game I can remember)

Perhaps, instead of reinventing the wheel, inspect the other guys' wheel and see if you can use the same technology to create what you need. GTA for example: http://www.gta4.net/map/

This should get you started: https://developers.google.com/maps/